# Logging exceptions in JSON format when working with threads

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I am writing a REST API in Python that is running in a Docker container (and going to run in Kubernetes). The logs will be extracted from stdout and I need to provide them in JSON format for easier monitoring and parsing. At the moment I use Flask and gunicorn. After a lot of testing, I figured a way to achieve what I wanted and wrote a minimal example. I was wondering whether this is the "proper" way to do it or whether there's a simpler solution.

Here is a minimal example:

**backend.py** (just using Flask: `python backend.py`)

```py
from flask import Flask

import json, logging, sys
import traceback
import time
from datetime import datetime

backend = Flask(__name__)
backend.config.from_object(__name__)

# Use built-in logging in json format
class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"
        timestamp = time.strftime(FORMAT, time.localtime())

        json_record = {
            "timestamp": timestamp,
            "level": getattr(record, "levelname", None),
            "file": getattr(record, "filename", None) + ":" + str(getattr(record, "lineno", None)),
            "message": getattr(record, "msg", None),
        }
        return json.dumps(json_record)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(JsonFormatter())
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Writing my own exception handler for json formatting
def exception_logging(exctype, value, tb):
    FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'
    timestamp = time.strftime(FORMAT, time.localtime())

    json_record = {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "level": "fatal",
        "exception": str(value),
        "exception_type": str(exctype),
        "message": traceback.format_tb(tb, 10),
    }
    print(json.dumps(json_record))

sys.excepthook = exception_logging


@backend.route("/my-route", methods=["GET"])
def status():
    logging.info("/my-route called")

    try:
        # here goes the actual code ...

        # something goes wrong ...
        raise RuntimeError("Test unhandled")

        return json.dumps({})
    except:
        exception_logging(*sys.exc_info())
        return json.dumps({})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    backend.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

**wsgi.py** (production mode with gunicorn: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 1 wsgi:backend`)

```py
from backend import backend

if __name__ == "__main__":
    backend.run()
```

When running it with gunicorn (probably because of the threading), I need to wrap the entire code in each route in a try-catch block, since setting sys.excepthook doesn't help with threads. This doesn't seem very elegant.